# Space complexity of an array of linked list node pointers

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list, space-complexity

Say I have an existing linked list. If I were to iterate through the linked list and put all the nodes in an array, what would the space complexity of this? It seems obvious that it would be O(N), but the thing is, I am not creating N new nodes, but rather storing the reference to those nodes in an array. The nodes already exist are already stored somewhere, so it seems no new space is being used.

Comment: The array takes new space, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's O(N), since you need to create an array with N entries. Granted the memory used for each entry in the array is much smaller than the memory for the node itself. But that's just a constant factor, which Big-O ignores.